# flume doesn't work with hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, flume

I seted  flume with two nodes.I want to load data from the slave01 to hdfs.
slave01:example-conf.properties

```
 agent.sources = baksrc
agent.channels = memoryChannel
agent.sinks =avro-forward-sink 
agent.sources.baksrc.type = exec
agent.sources.baksrc.command = tail -F /root/hadoo/test/data.txt
agent.sources.baksrc.checkperiodic = 1000
agent.sources.baksrc.channels =memoryChannel 
agent.channels.memoryChannel.type = memory
agent.channels.memoryChannel.keep-alive = 30
agent.channels.memoryChannel.capacity = 10000
agent.channels.memoryChannel.transactionCapacity = 10000
agent.sinks.avro-forward-sink.type = avro
agent.sinks.avro-forward-sink.hostname = master
agent.sinks.avro-forward-sink.port = 23004
agent.sinks.avro-forward-sink.channel = memoryChannel
```

master: example-conf.properties

```
agent.sources = avrosrc
agent.sinks =hdfs-write 
agent.channels = memoryChannel
agent.sources.avrosrc.type =avro
agent.sources.avrosrc.bind =master
agent.sources.avrosrc.port =23004
agent.sources.avrosrc.channels=memoryChannel
agent.channels.memoryChannel.type = memory
agent.channels.memoryChannel.keep-alive = 30
agent.channels.memoryChannel.capacity = 10000
agent.channels.memoryChannel.transactionCapacity =10000
agent.sinks.hdfs-write.type = hdfs
agent.sinks.hdfs-write.hdfs.path =hdfs://172.16.86.38:9000/flume/webdata
agent.sinks.hdfs-write.hdfs.rollInterval = 0   
agent.sinks.hdfs-write.hdfs.rollSize = 4000000  
agent.sinks.hdfs-write.hdfs.rollCount = 0   
agent.sinks.hdfs-write.hdfs.writeFormat = Text  
agent.sinks.hdfs-write.hdfs.fileType = DataStream  
agent.sinks.hdfs-write.hdfs.batchSize = 10  
agent.sinks.hdfs-write.channel=memoryChannel
```

Then i run a shell script:like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in {1..1000000}; do
    echo "test flume to Hbase $i" >>/root/hadoop/test/data.txt; 
    sleep 0.1; 
done
```

start flume: 
flume-ng agent --conf conf --conf-file example-conf.properties --name agent -Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console
I got no error on the console.

```
14/05/06 16:38:44 INFO source.AvroSource: Avro source avrosrc stopping: Avro source avrosrc: { bindAddress: master, port: 23004 }
14/05/06 16:38:44 INFO ipc.NettyServer: [id: 0x49f2de1b, /172.16.86.39:9359 :> /172.16.86.38:23004] DISCONNECTED
14/05/06 16:38:44 INFO ipc.NettyServer: [id: 0x49f2de1b, /172.16.86.39:9359 :> /172.16.86.38:23004] UNBOUND
14/05/06 16:38:44 INFO ipc.NettyServer: [id: 0x49f2de1b, /172.16.86.39:9359 :> /172.16.86.38:23004] CLOSED
```

but i can't see the file in hdfs,   Is there any problem with my configuration ?? 
I've tested it on master,it work fine.

Answer (score 0):

which version of flume do you use ?
have you set HADOOP_HOME?
does flume output the classpath with hadoop jar from HADOOP_HOME？
if you are use apache flume,then step by step:
1. set HADOOP_HOME
2. edit hadoop core-site.xml，make sure namenode ip is right.
3. use hdfs path:`agent.sinks.hdfs-write.hdfs.path =/flume/webdata`
4. start flume